# Positive divisor in the form $a^c+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Well, my friend asked me this one and unfortunately, I was unable to solve it. Here is the problem
Given a positive integers $a>2$. Prove that for all positive integer $b> 2$, the number $\frac{a^{2^b-1}-1}{a-1}$ always has a divisors in the form $a^c+1$ ($c$ is a non negative integers)

Edit: It should be $\frac{a^{2^b-1}-1}{a-1}$ instead of $\frac{a^{2^b-1}}{a-1}$

Comment: I suppose you mean $\frac{a^{2^b}-1}{a-1}$ and not $\frac{a^{2^b-1}}{a-1}$?

Comment: I don't understand something: for $\;a=b=3\;$ , we have $$\frac{a^{2^b-1}}{a-1}=\frac{3^7}2\notin\Bbb Z$$ What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Start with $a = 3,b = 3$. Then $$\frac{a^{2^b-1}-1}{a-1} = \frac{a^7-1}{a-1} = \frac{3^7-1}{3-1} = \frac{2187-1}{2} = 1093,$$ but $1093$ is prime, and not of the form $3^c + 1$. It's most likely indeed $\dfrac{a^{2^b} - 1}{a-1}$ that was intended.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean $\frac{a^{2^b}-1}{a-1}$ and not $\frac{a^{2^b-1}}{a-1}$ (the $-1$ not in the exponent, since, as has been pointed out by Joanpemo, it's otherwise not true),

we can see that
\begin{align}
\frac{a^{2^b}-1}{a-1}&=a^{2^b-1}+a^{2^b-2}+\cdots+a+1\\
&=a^{2^b-2}(a+1)+a^{2^b-4}(a+1)+\cdots+a^2(a+1)+1(a+1)\\
&=(a+1)(a^{2^b-2}+a^{2^b-4}+\cdots+a^2+1)
\end{align}
so that $a+1$ always divides $\frac{a^{2^b}-1}{a-1}$, and $a+1$ is of the form $a^c+1$ where $c$ is a nonnegative integer.

---

We can even go further and prove that $a^c+1$ divides $\frac{a^{2^b}-1}{a-1}$ if $c$ is a power of $2$ less than $2^b$. We see that
\begin{align}
\gcd(a^c+1,a^{2^b}-1)&=\gcd(a^c+1,a^{2^b}-1+(a^c+1))\\
&=\gcd(a^c+1,a^{2^b}+a^c)\\
&=\gcd(a^c+1,a^c(a^{2^b-c}+1))\\
&=\gcd(a^c+1,a^{2^b-c}+1)\\
&=\gcd(a^c+1,a^{2^b-c}+1-(a^c+1))\\
&=\gcd(a^c+1,a^{2^b-c}-a^c)\\
&=\gcd(a^c+1,a^c(a^{2^b-2c}-1))\\
&=\gcd(a^c+1,a^{2^b-2c}-1)\\
\end{align}
and we can repeat this process $k$ times to get 
$$\gcd(a^c+1,a^{2^b}-1)=\gcd(a^c+1,a^{2^b-2kc}-1)$$
So if $c$ is a power of $2$ less than $2^b$, then we can choose $k$ so that $2^b=2kc$, so that we get 
$$\gcd(a^c+1,a^{2^b}-1)=\gcd(a^c+1,a^{0}-1)=a^c+1$$
which means $a^c+1|a^{2^b}-1$, and now we only need to show that $\gcd(a^c+1,a-1)=1$. We know
\begin{align}
\gcd(a-1,a^c+1)&=\gcd(a-1,a^c+1+(a-1))\\
&=\gcd(a-1,a^c+a)\\
&=\gcd(a-1,a(a^{c-1}+1))\\
&=\gcd(a-1,a^{c-1}+1)\\
\end{align}
repeating this process $c$ times gives us $$\gcd(a-1,a^c+1)=\gcd(a-1,2)$$ So $\gcd(a^c+1,a-1)=1$ if $a$ is even. If $a$ is odd, then (for $c\geq2$, we handled $c=1$ already) $a^c+1\equiv (a^{c/2})^2+1\equiv 1+1\equiv 2\mod 4$, so $a^c+1$ contains exactly one factor $2$. But $\frac{a^{2^b}-1}{a-1}=a^{2^b-1}+a^{2^b-2}+\cdots+a+1$ is even (because there's an even number of terms), so the factor $2$ will not cause any problems. That concludes the proof.